# Node red in raspberry pi not receiving the commands

Tags: raspberry-pi, ibm-watson, node-red

I am trying to achieve a simple task. I would like to send the temperature from sense hat to the IBM Watson and receive it back. I am able to send the temperature from the sense hat to the IBM Watson but **I am unable to receive it back**. Although it shows connected but the **debug does not print anything**. Let me know if I am missing something.

[image: Node red flow]

[image: Temperature data in IBM Watson console]

Answer (score 2):

A Device connected to Watson IoT Platform is restricted in what topics it can publish and subscribe to.

The messages it sends to the platform are 'events' and must be published on an event topic of the form `iot-2/evt/event_id/fmt/format_string`.

It can also subscribe to 'commands' from the platform, using a command topic of the form `iot-2/cmd/command_id/fmt/format_string`.

This means a device cannot subscribe to its own events - it can only subscribe to its commands.

For more information about the MQTT connectivity for the platform, the documentation is [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/devices/mqtt.html#mqtt).